# Warning when byte compiling: the function 'whitespace-mode' might not be defined at runtime

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I put the following in `foo.el`:

```
(defun whitespace-redraw ()
  (eval-when-compile (require 'whitespace nil t))
  (when (require 'whitespace nil t)
    (if whitespace-mode
        (whitespace-mode 0))
    (whitespace-mode 1)))
```

and then byte compile it:

```
emacs -Q --batch --eval '(byte-compile-file "foo.el")'
```

I get the following warning:

```
In end of data:
foo.el:7:1:Warning: the function `whitespace-mode' might not be defined at
    runtime.
Wrote foo.elc
```

Certainly `whitespace-mode` can be undefined at runtime, but it should never be executed unless whitespace loads successfully.  If whitespace loads, then `whitespace-mode` will be defined.

Is this warning the result of an emacs compiler limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have been wondering about this so often. Never had any problems though and ignorance is sometimes bliss.

Comment: Just an update: as of Emacs 24.4, I don't see the warning on this code; I think the compiler is smarter now.

Answer (score 3):

I add here the response I put as a comment above, just for the record.

What the compiler says is that the function is defined at compile time, but it might not be present when you run the code (it tells you that you have to require it previously when you run the code). So it may be a good practice to `eval-when-compile` *only* if you just need macros defined in that package. If you need also functions and/or variables, you should just `require` the package, not under `eval-when-compile`, but always.

Comment: But it _is_ `require`d at runtime; note the `(when (require 'whitespace nil t) ...)` in the OP.  At the point the function is called, the function should _always_ be available because Emacs was able to successfully load the `whitespace` feature.  So either I have a really subtle bug or the compiler isn't capable of understanding that the function is guaranteed to be available if the function is going to be called.  I'd like to know which.

Comment: Yes, it is required at run-time, this is why I tell you to just `require` (without `eval-when-compile`) when you need that function to be available both at compile time and at run time. Take also into account that `when` is a macro, so it may not evaluate its arguments, so the compiler cannot actually know the require is going to be produced.

Comment: I want it to be available at compile time to silence warnings, but optional at run time (hence the `when` and `nil t`).  If I always require `whitespace`, then it'll break on installations without `whitespace`.

Comment: Your point about `when` being a macro is an interesting one.  However, the compiler does not print a warning when I do `(when (fboundp 'whitespace-mode) ...)`, so the compiler must have some understanding of `when`.  Right?

Comment: I think this is just because `when` is a macro. Then the compiler cannot guess when is it going to be evaluated (if ever).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: In this case there is no bug in your code, it's just that the byte compiler doesn't know where the function is defined.  It doesn't know that `whitespace-mode` is defined in `whitespace.el` since there is nothing to tell it that.  (Un)fortunately, it's not as smart as you are yet. :-)

Rather than using `require` it is often preferable to use `autoload`.  Then you can forget all about `require`ing since emacs (and the byte compiler) will know how to load the function when it is first called.

```
(autoload 'whitespace-mode "whitespace" nil t)
```

If you know that the function will already be loaded, you can use `declare-function` to tell the byte compiler that a function is defined in a certain file.  The syntax is `(declare-function FUNCTION FILE ARGLIST)`.  For your case it would be

```
(declare-function whitespace-mode "whitespace" (&optional ARG))
```

I usually put these right before the defun that uses them, but that's just for organizational purposes.

Of course either of these can mask a bug if what you put isn't actually true (the file doesn't define the function), but I suppose there's no way around that since `whitespace.el` might get deleted or changed and loading would fail.  I don't think that eventuality is worth protecting against in most cases though.

Comment: This silences the warning, but it doesn't answer my question.  I'm worried that there is a bug in the code.  If there is a bug, using `declare-function` will mask it.  If there is not a bug, then why is the compiler printing the warning?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood.  There is no bug in your code, it's a limitation of the byte compiler.  There is no way for it to know that `require`ing `whitespace` will define a function `whitespace-mode`, so it tells you it might not be defined.  Of course you and I both know that `whitespace-mode` is defined in the file `whitespace`, and all that `declare-function` does is tell the byte compiler that as well.  Adding the `declare-function` _could_ mask a bug, but you shouldn't have to use it often.  Actually, you should probably use `autoload` -- I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an explicit check to your code:

```
(defun whitespace-redraw ()
  (eval-when-compile (require 'whitespace nil t))
  (when (and (require 'whitespace nil t)
             (fboundp 'whitespace-mode))
      (if whitespace-mode
          (whitespace-mode 0))
      (whitespace-mode 1)))
```

But that might get cumbersome after a while.

Comment: I have done that already in my actual code, but I wanted to understand what's going on.  I'm worried that adding the explicit check might hide an actual problem with my code.

Comment: Well, you might indeed have a problem if the function is not defined at runtime. That's what the warning says. It's issued because at compile-time the compiler doesn't know about the function "whitespace-mode", so he's just pointing out to you that you better make sure it exists. If you byte compile like so: `emacs -Q --batch --eval "(require 'whitespace nil t) (byte-compile-file \"foo.el\"))"` then the compiler knows the function at compile time and will not issue a warning.

Comment: Thomas, I still don't get it. How come the compiler doesn't know about whitespace-mode at compile time if you explicitly say `(eval-when-compile (require 'whitespace))`?

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. What the compiler says is that the function is defined at compile time, but it might not be present when you run the code (it tells you that you have to require it previously when you run the code). So it may be a good practice to `eval-when-compile` *only* if you just need macros defined in that package. If you need also functions and/or variables, you should just `require` the package, not under `eval-when-compile`, but always.